# Interactive gridview with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I've been learning ASP.NET and I'm coding a gridview with an insert update delete functionality, and it's posting a persons basic information to a database.  I think I've ran into a dilemma though.  My database table has a persons first and last name with some other basic information, and everyone is identified by a unique PersonID.

My question is that when I do a new insert statement, will the user have to specify a unique personID in the gridview? or is it possible to have just automatically assign them the next sequential number in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that up in the database. For example, in MSSQL, you set the unique id to auto-increment.. you do so by going to the design view of the table, then once you do that you will click on the primary key, in your case 'personID' and in the column properties, you will scroll down and click the arrow to show more on Identity Specification. Then you change (Is Identity) to yes. But this is not the case if you are not using Microsoft Sql Server. You would have to look up the procedures to do it in MySql or whatever database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

No, The database should automatically generate the ID (assuming its the Primary key and you set the column as the identifier). As a general rule of thumb, you do not want to set the IDs.

If it is not generating them, going into SQL server and click design on a table, then with the column highlighted, there is a section called "Identity Specification" in the properties. you want "Is Identity" to be set to yes and The increment to be set to 1. Also, you can start it at 1 with the seed. hope that helps.